# Using Index and Match to extract data from a Table without row header

Tags: excel

I need to collect the SPL value in the following Table:

[image]

In my spreadsheet, I require the user to type in two specific pieces of information, the Name (headers) and then the distance, which is the numbers in my matrix( minus the last two columns)... Based on the user input I need to match the name and distance to find the SPL and PEL for that combination.

Originally I was trying to do something like

```
=INDEX(Wet_Suit_Un_Hooded9[SPL
(dB)],MATCH(Sheet1!C15,Wet_Suit_Un_Hooded9[[BSY-1]:[SQS-56]],1),MATCH(Sheet1!C13,Wet_Suit_Un_Hooded9[#Headers],0))
```

However I realized that MATCH will not work because I am asking it to find a value in a matrix and not an array. I was wondering what my options are to resolve this issue. Should I recreate the table to have every distance on one column and the SPL Data replace where the distance data is currently located... this way a INDEX MATCH can find the correct Row? OR is there another way around this, like nested IF statement depending on the Name selected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve the problem using INDEX(reference, row_num, [column_num], [area_num])

In the reference you can add areas like (A1:N100,B1:N100,C1:N100 ... till M1:N100)

The Final formula will be something like this

VLOOKUP(,INDEX((A1:N100,B1:N100,....),0,0,MATCH(,A1:M1,0)),<total columns i.e. 14>-MATCH(,A1:N1,0)+1,0)

Here we are creating multiple areas in Index formula and deciding the area to be searched by First match. The index function will return array which will be used in VLOOKUP.